# Standard way to map an ICANN domain to an .onion domain?

Tags: onion-services

Are there any standards for mapping ICANN domains-world websites to `.onion` addresses?

I’m interested in any machine-readable methods that can be used to discover a `.com`’s `.onion` domain.

E.g. is there a standard method to announce that `https://www.bbc.com/` is also available at `https://www.bbcnewsv2vjtpsuy.onion/`? Given the `.com`, how would I auto-discover (and ideally verify) the `.onion`? (This is obviously only applicable for real-world websites that offer a Tor hidden service mirror.)

The only resource I’ve found is the short manually curated list in the [Real-World Onion Websites](https://github.com/alecmuffett/real-world-onion-sites) project.

[I’ve dreamed up](https://twitter.com/DaAleksandersen/status/1202901091152801792) a `/.well-known/mirrors.txt` URI auto-discovery mechanism. That file would list all mirrors of a website. You could include your `.onion` address and your `.com` in that file. If the file is accessible from both location and contain each other than you’ve got a verified domain match between an `.onion` and an ICANN domain.

[RFC 8164](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8164) proposes something similar for auto-discovering HTTPS-support. The Dat protocol uses [something similar too](https://github.com/datprotocol/DEPs/blob/aec2791218d806ceca5ada59ff55783fa6710f5f/proposals/0005-dns.md).

Comment: I think the reason no one has responded is because it is more of a webserver question than merely a Tor question. My suggestion would be to contact Alec Muffett. You linked to his "Real-World Onion Websites project" and see if he can provide some illumination. He literally runs the onion service for Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tor has introduced a new HTTP response header for this purpose: [`Onion-Location`](https://community.torproject.org/onion-services/advanced/onion-location/).

Answer (score 0):

The header you're looking for is `Alt-Svc`; the most accessible write-up I've found is [Jonah Aragon's "Securing Services with Tor and alt-svc"](https://blog.jonaharagon.com/securing-services-with-tor-and-alt-svc/), but there are other guides and articles out there about it.  It works much the same as your `/.well-known/mirrors.txt` idea.

Comment: Cloudflare uses this but the addresses it assigns to customers are short-lived/unstable.